# Sending output from php script called from bash script to syslog

Tags: linux, php, bash, logging, syslog

Sending output from php script called from bash script to syslog

Im trying to create a bash script (to be called by a cron job) which calls a php file (which I have not made). Calling the php file is easy enough. The php script output a lot of stuff to stdout and I would like to redirect the output from the php script to logger so that I can monitor the progress in my remote syslog server.

I've tried something like:

`PHP_SCRIPT_PATH="/some/path"

ME=basename $0


LOGGER="logger -p cron.notice -t $ME"


cd $PHP_SCRIPT_PATH

php the_php_script.php &> eval $LOGGER`

Also tried:

`php the_php_script.php | eval $LOGGER`

But neither work.

Another possible solution I've considered is to pipe the output from the php script to a log file, and then have another bash script read that file and write each line to a logger. But I would like to have one script which does everything :)

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'd look if there isn't a syslog client implementation in php first and use logger if there's none : That will allow you to control logging line per line inside the_php_script.php; edit : http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calls to `logger` are failing because `$LOGGER` isn't the command. Try this instead:

```
LOGGER=logger
LOGGER_OPTS="-p cron.notice -t $ME"

php whatever.php | $LOGGER $LOGGER_OPTS
```

Comment: Wow, that was a fast reply

And it even works! Thanks a lot :)